# Create component like Page in QML, contains header-like Item

Tags: qml

We have a working code

```
Page {
    header: Item {}
}
```

I need to create a new template component in which I can then put the necessary components, just as we write our component in the property of the header, that is, I'm interested in how to make my analog header template.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer.

Template file Some.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    property alias content: column.children

    Column {
        id: column
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

and use it

```
import QtQuick 2.0

    Some {
        content: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 100
            color: "red"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might want to consider a different name, a `Container` component already exists in Quick Controls 2.2 and it behaves differently, which might cause some confusion